# MSB6003 cmd.exe Access Denied Visual Studio

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, c++

Error MSB6003 The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access Denied

When i try to compile any sort of code (currently working with Unreal Engine) on Visual Studio 2019 i get this error in the Visual Studio console.

This error persisted also with a fresh installation of Windows.

I couldn't find anything on Google related to this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out to be Comodo Firewall that was silently blocking Visual Studio.